# Run a batch file with Admin previlige

Tags: sharepoint, scripting, installation, batch-file

I have a sharepoint feature installer packaged as a batch file. The users should be able to run the .bat file and install the feature themselves in their environment with the admin previliges. Is there any command i can include in my .bat file to run it with elevated previliges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772672%28WS.10%29.aspx) provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach is to compile the bat file to exe.  Using a utility such as http://www.bdargo.com/ you can add an "Manifest Token" which will prompt the user to allow it to run with elevated privileges.

Note: I'm not affiliated with that company.